# Callback vs Await Performance in Express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, web, callback

People say that `async/await` is just another way to write callbacks for promises. However, I feel as though they are not interchangeable; in fact, callbacks would be better in Express because it returns the result to the user right away. Is this correct?

In the following example, let's say we don't care about the result of `doSomethingAsync()`, but want to redirect right away. Here, we use `await`.

```
router.get('/register', async (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')           
    await doSomethingAsync()
    console.log(1)
}

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(2)
    ...
}
```

This would print out `1`, then `2`, meaning that we won't be able to exit the `/register` handler and redirect unless the async function finishes.

In the below version, we use a promise with a callback in `then`.

```
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')           
    doSomethingAsync().then(() => {
        console.log(1)
    })
}

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log(2)
   ...
}
```

This would print out `2`, then `1`, meaning that we can exit immediately and redirect the user.
Isn't the second way better for performance? Or are they actually the same?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the both ways have the same performances. But if you want to be sure, you can use the console.timer("myTimer") and then the console.timeEnd("myTimer") to se the time it used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> People say that `async/await` is just another way to write callbacks for promises. However, I feel as though they are not interchangeable;

That is incorrect, and they are indeed interchangeable. In fact, `async/await` allows you to do things *more easily* than with plain promises, since an `await` expression can be inserted into virtually any control flow logic seamlessly, while you cannot do so with plain promises, and are required to chain them using sequential `.then()` calls.

> In fact, callbacks would be better in Express because it returns the result to the user right away. Is this correct?

No. A callback is a different mechanism for delivering data asynchronously; it is not "right away", nor is it significantly faster, and the benefits of programming with promises far outweigh any negligible performance implications of resorting to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). In addition, your second example is not a true callback, it is a promise chain.

> This would print out `1`, then `2`, meaning that we won't be able to exit the `/register` handler and redirect unless the async function finishes.

That is incorrect. [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is non-blocking. The [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) returns to the caller as soon as `doSomethingAsync()` is invoked, and the [`async` function's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) return value is a promise that is resolved after `console.log(1)` has been invoked.

> This would print out `2`, then `1`, meaning that we can exit immediately and redirect the user. Isn't the second way better for performance? Or are they actually the same?

The two snippets are algorithmically the same, and since the `console.log(2)` is dependent on the client's browser performing the HTTP request indicated by [`res.redirect('/')`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) which is independent of `doSomethingAsync()`, you actually have a race condition, and neither order of logs is guaranteed. Its performance is also *no different* than the example using `await`.

Comment: i think in the fast-moving world of javascript explanations like these should be provided by feature B trying to replace feature A. Otherwise people just assume feature A is outdated\bad\woks differently

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! To make sure, when you say it invokes the instructions below await and returns immediately, what happens if there is a line below that uses the result of the await ? ` router.get('/register', async (req, res) => { res.redirect('/') var result = await doSomethingAsync(); console.log(1); console.log(result) }`

Here, you say that `console.log(1)` will be invoked before the promise resolves, but will `console.log(result)` also be invoked?

Comment: "when you say it invokes the instrunctions below await" -- I did not say that. I said it invokes `doSomethingAsync()`. The function then returns immediately and the statements after `await` are not invoked until after the promise returned by `doSomethingAsync()` is resolved.